# problem in viewing others user profile (asp.net )

Tags: asp.net, database, sql-server-2005, asp.net-ajax

i am creating site like say LinkedIn/spoke

like when i login ,i give my login id and password so database 
checks it and allow me to access my profile

i need to know that in stackoverflow when we click to users
 button all the users in stackoverflow are shown 
but when i click to specific user 
how does the database known that this specific user is clicked 
and show's his/her profile data ?

should i create new page for viewing others user profile ?
and if i do so what will be the query for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 seperate queries then it makes easier (I'm not saying this is the best solution).  So, you could have a 'select all users' query which could be something as simple as :

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyUsers
```

This will return all of your users to your website, so you can view them.  Then, when you select a user from your website, you call a different query, say 'select a single user', and pass a parameter from your website.  The query could look something like :

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyUsers
 WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

This could be done in one stored procedure and test if your `@UserID` is `NULL` then run the required `SELECT` statement.